# How to avoid multiple insert in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

In my query im using for loop. Each and every time when for loop is executed, at the end some values has to be inserted into table. This is time consuming because for loop has many records. Due to this each and every time when for loop is executed, insertion is happening. Is there any other way to perform insertion at the end after the for loop is executed.

```
For i in 1..10000 loop .... 
    --coding 
    insert into datas.tb values(j,predictednode); -- j and predictednode are variables which will change for every loop
End loop;
```

Instead of inserting each and every time i want the insertion should happen at the end.

Comment: how your variables are changing? it could be possible to do this in one insert

Comment: j variable will have the value from another for loop and predicted node will have the value based on same calculation

Comment: You could use a before insert trigger to raise an error or redirect to the correct table.

Comment: what version of PostgreSQL do you using?

Comment: @user2659199 it highly depends on type of calculation your' doing. It could be aggregate or some simple calculation or anything else. It would be easier for you to get good answer if your question would be more specific

Comment: This query is for Trees. That is node evaluation. If parent condition is true then it will go for child else it will go for siblings. This process will goes on until it predicts the correct node. The final correct node is the predictednode

Comment: @user2659199 can you post you schema and desired result? I'm pretty sure I can help you and give answer with single query, but I need sample input data and sample output data

Comment: -1 (-1T if I could) You should give some more information, with only that info you are making people try to guess the solution, and so nobody will give you the **best solution**, just some taken from their crystal... A lot of people asked and you gave no valuable information... This question should be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you show how the variables are calculated it could be possible to build something like this:

```
insert into datas.tb
select
    calculate_j_here,
    calculate_predicted_node_here
from generate_series(1, 10000)
```

Comment: j variable will have the value from another for loop and predicted node will have the value based on same calculation

Comment: @user If you don't show it you will only get very generic answers.

Comment: For j in 1..10000 loop   -- 10000 for example                                                                             For i in 1..10000 loop                                                    .... 
    predictednode = 34; -- consider some value 
    insert into datas.tb values(j,predictednode); -- j and predictednode are variables which will change for every loop
End loop; End Loop;

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to build a large `VALUES` String. In Java, something like

```
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(100000); // big enough?
for ( int i=1; i<=10000; ++i ) {
    buf.append("(")
       .append(j)
       .append(",")
       .append(predicted_node)
       .append("),"); // whatever j and predict_node are
}
buf.setCharAt(buf.length()-1, ' '); // kill last comma
String query = "INSERT INTO datas.tb VALUES " + buf.toString() + ";"
// send query to DB, just once
```

The fact `j` and `predict_node` appear to be constant has me a little worried, though. Why are you putting a constant in 100000 times?

Another approach is to do the predicting in a Postgres procedural language, and have the DB itself calculate the value on insert.